# How to validate datepicker range using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to validate date,so in below html End date should always be greater than start date, I used  k-min and k-rebind that is working for user its disabling start date numbers, but with that implementation user can go back and select higher start date so here i implement AngularJS custom validation if end date is less than start date throw validation error but its not wokring with below code...

main.html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="cycleStart" class="col-md-4 required">Cycle Start</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input kendo-date-picker
        type="text" class="form-control" id="cycleStart"
        name="cycleStart"
        ng-model="rcsaCycleDTO.cycStartDate" 
        k-ng-model="cycleStrtObj"
        onkeydown="return false;"
        ng-change="validateDate()"
        required data-required-msg="Cycle start is required">
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="createRcsaCycleForm.cycleStart.$touched && createRcsaCycleForm.cycleStart.$error.required">Cycle Start is required field</p>                                
    </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="cycleEnd" class="col-md-4 required">Cycle end (due date)</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input 
        kendo-date-picker
        type="text" class="form-control" id="cycleEnd"
        name="cycleEnd"
        ng-model="rcsaCycleDTO.cycEndDate"
        k-min="cycleStrtObj" 
        k-rebind="cycleStrtObj"
        onkeydown="return false;"
        ng-change="validateDate()"
        required>
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="createRcsaCycleForm.cycleEnd.$touched && createRcsaCycleForm.cycleEnd.$error.required">Cycle End is required field</p>
        <p class="text-danger" ng-show="createRcsaCycleForm.cycleEnd.$error.valid"> Name already existed</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
$scope.validateDate = function(){
          var startDate = $scope.rcsaCycleDTO.cycStartDate;
          var endDate = $scope.rcsaCycleDTO.cycEndDate;
          if (endDate <= startDate) {
            $scope.createRcsaCycleForm.cycleEnd.$setValidity('valid',false);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Date.parse` and then comparing the dates.

```
    $scope.validateDate = function(){
      var startDate = Date.parse($scope.rcsaCycleDTO.cycStartDate);
      var endDate = Date.parse($scope.rcsaCycleDTO.cycEndDate);
      if (stateDate > endDate) {
        $scope.createRcsaCycleForm.rcsaName.$setValidity('valid',false);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This function is not even executing on value change and showing error on if statement (Syntax error "this can be merge to form") i am not sure what is wrong with code. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is showing on the if statement?

Comment: i cleared the error but function is still not executing on value change...do we need to do something with $watch ?

Comment: I didn't understand. Is the validation logic working correctly?

Comment: yes logic is working correctly its getting both dates in comparison but its not showing error message...

Comment: There must be a different error in your other part of the code.

Comment: $scope.createRcsaCycleForm.cycleEnd.$setValidity('valid',false); is coming undefined